# PHP: split a sentence along commas, except for parallel structures

Tags: php, text, nlp, sentence

I would like to split a setnence into parts along commas, except if it contains a paralllel structure.

For example, given these sentences (http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/623/01/):

> Mary likes to hike, to swim, and to ride a bicycle.
>
> Mary likes to hike, swim, and ride a bicycle.

I would split these along the first comma only so I would get:

```
sentence_array ( "Mary likes to hike", "swim, and ride a bicycle")
```

Perhaps with a forward looking regex, checking for at least 2-3 white spaces not surrounded by a comma?

Comment: If you're trying to not split up the parallelism, shouldn't you technically not be splitting it apart at all since "to hike" is part of that parallel phrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this could work:

```
<?php

$str = "Mary likes to hike, to swim, and to ride a bicycle, also, something more at the end.";
var_dump($str);

$str = preg_replace('/((\s\w*){3,},)/', '\1*', $str);
$str = explode('*', $str);

var_dump($str);
?>
```

It has to be worked on tho like using something more unique than a mere `*`

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a hard time understand what is actually that you want?
Would explode(',', 'Mary likes to hike, swim, and ride a bicycle', 2) work? hence the 2 in there (limit)
Or is it that you want to explode by ', ' ?

Comment: Yes I would like to split by comma, and skip splitting following commas if they are too close, say within 2 words.

Comment: The 'within 2 words' thingy calls for regular expression

Answer (score 0):

use `explode(separator,string,limit)`

or

`split ( string $pattern , string $string [, int $limit = -1 ] )`

Comment: Tested it, the limit -1 excludes the last item of the explode array, but I would like to keep it. Also, I would only like to split by a comma if there is some distance from the previous comma, say 3-4 words, otherwise we have a parallel structure.

Comment: then you can use just explode(separator,string)

Comment: would you please give me an example that what is your input and what do you want to as output?

Comment: thx, there is one in the issue desc. I think I will build a look behind or ahead regex for this.